# Prediction does not change although applying different test data in scikitlearn (GPR)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Using following data `(X= test data, y= target data, x= test data)` I want to perform GPR-prediction in Scikit-Learn Regression:

```
X= np.array([[43.3301, -196.211, 1157.89, 2.71431, -191.664, 1159.45, 
-28.9847,  -191.544, 1158.88, 5.99311, -218.226, 1229.12],

[43.3212, -196.12, 1157.79, 2.7885, -191.587, 1159.45,
-29.0067, -191.53, 1158.88, 5.94141, -218.028, 1229.11],

[43.2683, -195.597, 1157.93, 2.73207, -191.123, 1159.45,
-29.0409, -191.025, 1158.98, 5.90694, -217.163, 1229.18],

[43.2876, -194.996, 1158.02, 2.73876, -190.575, 1159.49,
-29.1242, -190.445, 1159.04, 5.70859, -216.194, 1229.23],

[43.3158, -194.447, 1158.05, 2.72303, -190.022, 1159.47,
-29.1352, -189.92, 1159.07, 5.70269, -215.175, 1229.24 ]]) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (5, 12)

y= np.array([[ 9.14779,  -186.67,     1294.53 ],
             [ 9.12453,  -186.559,    1294.33 ],
             [ 8.50554,  -186.254,    1293.22 ],
             [ 7.94586,  -185.972,    1291.67 ],
             [ 7.32336,  -185.646,    1290.63 ]]) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (5, 3)

x= np.array ([[90.23126221, 245.30821228,  675.83514404,
               63.30067444, 256.12649536,  752.84460449,
               28.84734154, -236.44929504,  642.7713623 ,
               7.27009201, -244.59780884,  708.88665771]]) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1, 3)

kernel = ConstantKernel(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10.0, (1e-2, 1e2)) + WhiteKernel(0.1, (1e-10, 0.5))

gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel= kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=0, normalize_y= True)
gpr.fit(X, y)

y_Pred, sigma = gpr.predict(x, return_std= True)
print('\ny_Pred: ', y_Pred, type(y_Pred), y_Pred.shape)

rms = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y[0], y_Pred.T))
print('\nrms: ', rms)
```

My problem is: if I change the values of `test data (x)` even radically, the prediction result `y_Pred 1x3 array` does not change.
What can be the problem here?
Thank you for any suggestion.

**Edit:**
I also tried it with different kernels:

```
kernel1 = ConstantKernel(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10.0, (1e-2, 1e2)) + WhiteKernel(0.1, (1e-10, 0.5))
kernel2 = 1.0 * RBF(length_scale= 1.0, length_scale_bounds= (1e-1, 10.0))
kernel3 = 1.0 * RBF(length_scale= 100.0, length_scale_bounds= (1e-2, 1e3)) + WhiteKernel(noise_level= 1, noise_level_bounds= (1e-10, 1e+1))
kernel4 = 1.0 * RationalQuadratic(length_scale= 1.0, alpha= 0.1)
kernel5 = 1.0 * ConstantKernel(constant_value= 1.0, constant_value_bounds= (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(length_scale= 10, length_scale_bounds= (1e-2, 1e2))
kernel6 = 1.0 * ExpSineSquared(length_scale= 1.0, periodicity=3.0, periodicity_bounds= (1e-2, 1e1)) + WhiteKernel(noise_level= 1, noise_level_bounds= (1e-10, 1e+1))
kernel7 = Matern(length_scale= 1.0, length_scale_bounds= (1e-1, 10.0), nu= 1.5)
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the constant kernel. Try another kernel.

Comment: @Thomas Lang I tried it already. Please see my edit in the post.

Comment: Hm, this suggests that your model is totally underfitting. Check the dimensionality of `y` against the documentation, maybe you need to reshape your data.

Comment: According doc `y : array-like, shape = (n_samples, [n_output_dims])` and in my case the `n_output_dims` is `3`. In which dimension should I reshape it?

Comment: Another thing to try: Perform a grid search over model paramters and collect all results. If the result is really the same over all possible parameters, we're in deep shit here. Otherwise this helps optimizing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could come from training dataset `X` : it has a very low variance, all the transactions are pretty similar and quite far from the `x` you are trying to predict ...